# pandas read_csv error when loading a plain CSV file

Tags: python, windows, path

I am having this very weird error with python pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:\Temp\test.csv', index_col=None, comment='#', sep=',')
```

The test.csv is a very simple CSV file created in Notepad:

```html
aaa,bbb,date
hhhhh,wws,20220701
```

Now I get the error:

```
  File "C:\test\untitled0.py", line 10, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv('C:\temp\test.csv', index_col=None, comment='#', sep=',')

  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 586, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 482, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)

  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 811, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)

  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1040, in _make_engine
    return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]

  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py", line 51, in __init__
    self._open_handles(src, kwds)

  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\base_parser.py", line 229, in _open_handles
    errors=kwds.get("encoding_errors", "strict"),

  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 707, in get_handle
    newline="",

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\temp\test.csv'
```

I also tried to use Excel to export a CSV file, and get the same error.

Does anyone know what goes wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a python string, the backslash in `'\t'` is an escape character which causes those two characters ( `\` followed by `t`) to mean `tab`. You can get around this using [`raw strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) by prefacing the opening quote with the letter 'r':

```py
r'C:\Temp\test.csv'
```